# Spring Boot configuration is missing from Run/Debug Configuration

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, configuration

I'm using Intellij 2019.2.4 ultimate.

For reference

[image]

Comment: Did you enable Spring (Boot) support in the plugin section.

Comment: it was disabled, problem solved after I enabled the plugin. thanks !